# How to correctly handle anyType() from web service?

Tags: java

My service will usually return something like:

```
anyType{Acc1=96628; Code=E; OnArr=false; CanArr=true; Username=ANDERSON;}
```

which I am then pushing to my object with

```
details.Username = response.getProperty("Username").toString();
```

and that works, just as I need it, until I get a response which doesn't have a value for the username, which comes back as follows:

```
anyType{Acc1=96628; Code=E; OnArr=false; CanArr=true; Username=anyType{};}
```

When I later call the details.Username, it returns "anyType{}" (as a string), rather than returning either and empty string

Can you tell me what am I missing?

For clarity on how I got to the `response`...

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodName);

PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
propertyInfo.setName("Details");
propertyInfo.setValue(details);
propertyInfo.setType(details.getClass());
request.addProperty(propertyInfo);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Details", Details.class);

HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
httpTransportSE.call(NAMESPACE + methodName, envelope);

SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

**[EDIT]**

The following seems to have done the trick; although, I am not quite sure why or if it's the correct approach.

```
details.Username = response.getPrimitivePropertyAsString("Username");
```

Comment: does it always say `anyType{}` when there is no real value?

Comment: Yes, even when I changed the service to return an empty string (rather than a NULL) it still comes back the same.

Comment: Can you give what is the Class type of `response`

Comment: response is a SoapObject (have extended the OP to include further details on how I get to response

Comment: @isaace - response.getPrimitivePropertyAsString("Username") seem to have fixed it

Comment: `That's great!`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be resolved with

```
details.Username = response.getPrimitivePropertyAsString("Username");
```

Poking into the **SoapObject.java**, I can see the sense behind it, too

```
/**
 * Get the toString value of a property without chance of throwing an
 * exception. An object can be provided to this method; if the property is
 * not found, this object's string representation will be returned.
 *
 * @param defaultThing
 *            toString of the object to return if the property is not found
 * @return the property toString if it exists; defaultThing toString if the
 *         property does not exist, if the defaultThing is null #EMPTY_STRING
 *         is returned
 */

public String getPropertySafelyAsString(final String namespace,final String name,
                                        final Object defaultThing) {
    Integer i = propertyIndex(namespace,name);
    if (i != null) {
        Object property = getProperty(i.intValue());
        if (property != null) {
            return property.toString();
        } else {
            return EMPTY_STRING;
        }
    } else {
        if (defaultThing != null) {
            return defaultThing.toString();
        } else {
            return EMPTY_STRING;
        }
    }
}
```